# Delete a conversation just for 1 user in a chat app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am implementing a chat app using nodejs and mongodb. I've created models: conversation and messages.

```
Message.js
conversationId: {
        //conversationID
    },
    body: {
        //messsagebody
    },
    author: {
        //sender
    },
    date: {
        
    }

Conversation.js
participants: {
        //an array of sender and receiver(users)
}
```

I created endpoints to get messages for an user, to get messages of a conversation between users. I find it difficult to implement endpoints to delete a conversation or messages for a logged in user. Because it would delete the conversation for another user also. How can I achieve my goal to delete a conversation for only 1 user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would either have to duplicate the conversation for all participants, and each participant only sees their copy. Or, you can put some kind of a visibility flag on the conversation, which sets who can see/not see the content. That way it's 'deleted' for one user but not another.

Comment: how can I modify that visibilty flag just for one user?

Comment: Depends on whether you want an inclusive model or exclusive one.

e.g.
List everyone who can see the conversation:
visibility: [user1, user2, user3....]

Allow everyone except certain people to see the conversation:
exclude: [user2]

Answer (score 0):

Dont delete the whole conversation, just add participant id in messages schema and while deleting the conversation just update id of the user who delete the conversation in messages schema of that conversatiion..then while getting message of conversation use login where user not have id in message schema